# AngularJS update only once while asynchrous call is processing

Tags: angularjs

I have the ability to seed data via the controller such as this:

https://jsfiddle.net/0nbu1uaL/2/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('myService', function($timeout) {
        var _myValue = null;
    return {
            value: function() {
            // May be called more than once
            return _myValue;
        },
        UpdateValue: function() {
            $timeout(function() {
                _myValue = "Hello World!"
            }, 3000);
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.value = myService.value;
    myService.UpdateValue();
});
```

But I want my service to know when to populate local data based on condition, such as this:

https://jsfiddle.net/q783gjor/2/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('myService', function($timeout) {
        var _isUpdating = false;
        var _myValue = null;
    myService = {};
     myService.UpdateValue = function() {
              _isUpdating = true;
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log('processed timeout')
                _myValue = "Hello World!"
                _isUpdating = false;
            }, 3000);
        };
     myService.value = function() {
            // May be called more than once
            if (_myValue == null && _isUpdating == false) {
                  myService.UpdateValue();
            }
            console.log('value() called')
            return _myValue;
        };

    return myService;
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.value = myService.value;
});
```

Is there a method to do the second without keeping a local 'isUpdating' variable to track state? Since value() is called multiple times I need a clean method of calling UpdateValue() only once (at a time)

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want here. Do you want every UpdateValue() call to execute, but one after another? Like in a queue?

Comment: I want UpdateValue() to be called whenever 'value' is stale, in this case stale meaning 'null'